# How to Fix ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: when installing tensorflow_recommenders using pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to install tensorflow-recommenders using pip but I keep getting this error.

I made sure I had Tensorflow 2.x installed and upgraded, but I keep getting the same error after running this command:

`pip install tensorflow-recommenders`

Error:

```
     command: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/wy/j6rljpj50y326hn2s45p1svc0000gn/T/pip-install-94eA0b/tensorflow-recommenders/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/wy/j6rljpj50y326hn2s45p1svc0000gn/T/pip-install-94eA0b/tensorflow-recommenders/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/wy/j6rljpj50y326hn2s45p1svc0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-n6vhs1
         cwd: /private/var/folders/wy/j6rljpj50y326hn2s45p1svc0000gn/T/pip-install-94eA0b/tensorflow-recommenders/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/wy/j6rljpj50y326hn2s45p1svc0000gn/T/pip-install-94eA0b/tensorflow-recommenders/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        import pathlib
    ImportError: No module named pathlib
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried everything I could, so if anyone has any suggestions it'd be super helpful!

Comment: Use Python 3 instead of 2.7.

Comment: It's still showing me the same error

Comment: Then you're still using Python 2.7